# How to use JFreeChart?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

It might be a silly question but I didn't figured it out how to use it.

I have downloaded JFreeChart from

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfreechart/files/latest/download?source=files

and I don't use Eclipse or Netbeans or Intellij or any other. How can I compile my project within these files on command line ?

Thanks is advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract zip file you have just downloaded. Copy jars from lib folder to your lib folder and add all the jars to your classpath using `-cp` switch.

However what are you going to do then? If you do not use IDE you can write code using any editor you want however it is at least 10 times slower than using IDE. Managing dependencies manually and compiling code using command line compiler is possible too but it starts to be extremely complicated and time consuming once you have external dependencies (as in your case).

So, if you want to create something beyond hello world take you time and start working with build tool like maven or gradle and IDE.

Suppose that I have my project structure as following:

```
hello
    src
       Hello.java
    classes
    lib
      one.jar
      two.jar
```

In this case I have compile it using command

```
javac -cp ../lib/one.jar:../lib/two.jar Hello.java
```

run this command from `src` folder. 
Use `;` instead of `:` if you are on windows.

Comment: I'm greatful for your attention, I'm using emacs with jde, I didn't figured it out with -cp , javac -cp like "lib/lib/temp.java:lib/lib/temp.java" could you gimme a more speficy please. I also have tried -classpath

Comment: Please see additions to my answer. And I still do not understand why do you prefer to work hard? Why emacs?

Comment: @AlexR Yeah, VIM rules EMACS any time! ;-)

Comment: I have compiled it,I know Its been hard but I trying to learn is it bad ? thank you for your time :) , And it is working fine ^^

Comment: @alexr why should I show my code ? , It worked fine already thanks to your answer.